# Better bash script to read two entries of each line of file into two variables

Tags: linux, bash

On CentOS linux, I have `/etc/fstab` that includes following entries:

```
/dev/dsk/xfsvold00     /mnt/00vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
/dev/dsk/xfsvold01     /mnt/01vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
/dev/dsk/xfsvold02     /mnt/02vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
/dev/dsk/xfsvold03     /mnt/03vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
/dev/dsk/xfsvold04     /mnt/04vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
/dev/dsk/xfsvold05     /mnt/05vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
/dev/dsk/xfsvold06     /mnt/06vol    xfs    defaults   0     2
```

I am developing a bash script that does filesystem mount. I am trying
to get first two entries of each line in `/etc/fstab` into two variables
and use those variables in mounting. For instance, I need:

```
dev/dsk/xfsvold00     /mnt/00vol
dev/dsk/xfsvold01     /mnt/01vol
dev/dsk/xfsvold02     /mnt/02vol
dev/dsk/xfsvold03     /mnt/03vol
```

I have the below working prototype code.

```
mountall() {
  # TODO: find a neat trick to get mntvol and mntpt.
  cat /etc/fstab | grep xfs > /tmp/tmpfstab
  while read mntvol mntpt var3; do
    mount -t xfs $mntvol $mntpt;
    rc=$?
    [ $rc -ne 0 ] && return $rc || echo "mount successful on $mntpt"
  done < /tmp/tmpfstab
  /bin/rm -rf /tmp/tmpfstab
  }
```

Is there a better implementation ? Any pointers or tips appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just do `mount -a` as the entries are in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Yep, I tried mount -a. It did not work (for some reason).

Comment: I see useless use of `cat` there...

Comment: Check [validating fstab](http://serverfault.com/questions/174181/how-do-you-validate-fstab-without-rebooting). Good luck :)

Comment: If `mount -a` is not working and you don't have `noauto` in the options it would do well to figure out why.

Comment: Also the following useful feature of `mount` which means you dont't need two entries. "When mounting a filesystem mentioned in fstab or mtab, it suffices to give only the device, or only the mount point."

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37267998/3744681) and [@Jahid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37268241/3744681) (thank you guys), code with slightly stringent check on filesystem type:

```
mountall () {
    awk '$3=="xfs"' /etc/fstab |
    while read -r mntvol mntpt var3; do
      mount -t xfs $mntvol $mntpt &&
       echo "mount successful on $mntpt" ||
       echo "mount failed on $mntpt" 
    done
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the extra subshell (by piping) with: `done < <(awk '$3=="xfs"' /etc/fstab)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked as well. Albeit, it seems #!/bin/bash is required for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are exiting the loop on the first failure. Fixing the warts along the way, you want

```
mountall () {
    grep xfs /etc/fstab |
    while read -r mntvol mntpt var3; do
      mount -t xfs $mntvol $mntpt &&
       echo "mount successful on $mntpt"
    done
 }
```

If the intent is really to abort on the first failure, switch the `&& echo` back to a `|| return`.

Answer (score 1):

I see several quirks:

1. There's no need for `cat /etc/fstab | grep xfs`, grep can take a file argument: `grep xfs /etc/fstab`
2. There's no need to put `$?` into a variable and then comparing the variable with a test command; you could just do: `if command;then echo success;else echo failure;fi` or `command && echo success || echo failure`

I would do it like this:

```
mountall(){
  while read -r mntvol mntpt var3; do
    if mount -t xfs $mntvol $mntpt; then 
      echo "mount successful on $mntpt"
    else
      echo "mount failed on $mntpt"
      return $? # comment this out if you don't want to stop here.
    fi
  done < <(grep xfs /etc/fstab)
}
```